# Is there any tangible difference between a unique clustered index and a clustered primary key?

Tags: sql-server-2005, index, primary-key, clustered-index

I understand that there may be a difference in *meaning* or *intent* between the two, but are there any behavioral or performance differences between a clustered primary key and a clustered unique index?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One main difference is that the unique index can have a NULL value that is not allowed in the primary key. Clustered or not, this is the main difference between the practical implementation of a Primary Key versus a Unique Key.

Oh, and the fact that a table can have one PK and many UK :-).

These are both differences in INTENT not in PERFORMANCE.
Otherwise, I don't think there's any difference.
Behind any PK or UK the SQL Server builds an index (depending on the request, clustered or not) and the way it's used is transparent for the source is coming from.

Comment: So there's no reason to use a PK, except (A) as an alias for `NOT NULL UNIQUE CLUSTERED` or (B) to highlight that a particular UQ is "special" in a metadata sense, even though the RDMS is agnostic?

Comment: Yes, something like that, I'd go for option B myself :-).

Comment: There is a reason - to stop you using the special value NULL where it is inappropriate!

Comment: @JamesRyan: That's covered by Jon of All Trades's reason #A.

Comment: @AndriyM no it isn't, you missed a subtilty. A null constraint can be missing or removed from a regular index, not from a PK.

Comment: @JamesRyan: Yes, between `PRIMARY KEY` and `NOT NULL UNIQUE`, the former would be much harder to turn into `NULL UNIQUE` (particularly if the constraint was already referenced by a foreign key). Would certainly prevent accidental changes from `NOT NULL` to `NULL`.

Answer (score 8):

Between a clustered primary key and a unique clustered index there isn't any different other than the unique clustered index can have a NULL value.

A non-unique clustered index has a uniqueifier that has to be dealt with for non-unique values.

Comment: Do you mean that further indexes on that table point directly to the rows in the clustered index ignoring the index created by the primary key?

Comment: That is correct.  Non-Clustered indexes will point to the clustering key, not the primary key.  If the primary key is a non-clustered key then all it does is enforce uniqueness on a column which doesn't support NULL values so that it can be used via a foreign key.