# Difference between Clustered Index and Unique Clustered Index?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, index, clustered-index

I got difference between clustered index and unique index [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303995/what-is-a-difference-between-clustered-index-and-unique-index). But what is the exact difference between `clustered index` and `unique-clustered index`?

AFAIK creating clustered index can be done for a column having unique values and if value is duplicate then clustered index cannot be set. Same is the case with unique-clustered index.

So i want to know the difference between them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any tangible difference between a unique clustered index and a clustered primary key?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/771/is-there-any-tangible-difference-between-a-unique-clustered-index-and-a-clustere)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a `UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX` only on a column (or combination of columns) that contains no duplicate data. The fact that you create the index with the `UNIQUE` keyword means that you are now constraining users from adding non unique data. (in the key column(s) of the clustered index)

A `CLUSTERED INDEX` can be created on a column (or combination of columns) that contains duplicate data. So in this case, the clustered index is not constraining you from adding non unique key data.

However, since a clustered index key is the row identifier, it needs to be able to uniquely identify a row, even if it's created on a column containing duplicate entries. Because of this, if you create a `CLUSTERED INDEX` for every row that is a duplicate, SQL Server adds a 4 byte uniquifier to the row, so that the index in fact becomes unique. This is all done under the hood.